# Anaconda: Tensorflow installs to .local when installed with pip

Tags: tensorflow, pip, anaconda

Whenever I install Tensorflow with pip from within an Anaconda environment, it seems to be saved to the `$/HOME/.local/` directory, rather than the corresponding `anaconda2/env/` directory. For example

```
$ source activate foo  # No TensorFlow Installed
(foo) $ pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
(foo) $ python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__file__
$HOME/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py'
```

I'd expect the last line to say something like
`$HOME/anaconda2/envs/foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py`
rather than pointing to some absolute directory.

Answer (score 1):

Although not 100% satisfactory, my work around (based off this [git issue thread](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/448)) is to make sure the environment variable `PYTHONNOUSERSITE` is set to `True` before installing tensorflow with pip. So, the new code is:

```
$ export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=True   # <--- DO THIS FIRST
$ source activate foo
(foo) $ pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
(foo) $ python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__file__
$HOME/anaconda2/envs/foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py
```